# How can I enable next button only if success?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, vue.js

This is my button which I click for moving to the next tab

```
<button type="submit" class='btn btn-next btn-primary' name='next' value='Next'>Next</button>
```

How can I enable this, only if the status is true

```
success: function(e) {
  if (e.status) {
    alert("Success")
    vm.pid = e.pid;
    console.log(vm.pid);
  } else {
    vm.response = e;
    alert("Registration Failed")
  }
}
```

How can I move to next tab only if alert= success?

Comment: can you please provide more details of your html page @med

Answer (score 0):

try this,

wrote a sample function .. by default it will be disabled, if you write something button will enable. no jquery used native javascript

```js
document.getElementById("next").disabled = true;
function do_enable(e=true) {
    if (e)
    {
     alert("Success")
      /*vm.pid=e.pid;
      console.log(vm.pid);*/
      document.getElementById("next").disabled = false;
      
  }
    else {
      vm.response = e;

     alert("Registration Failed") 
    }
}
```

```html
<input type="text" id="status" onchange="do_enable()" placeholder="say something">
<button type="submit" id="next" class='btn btn-next btn-primary' name='next' value='Next'>Next</button>
```

Comment: hello sir.. i need to move forward only if i get alert success

Answer (score 0):

Use `:disabled` to enable or disable button using Vue. [Read more.](https://v2.vuejs.org/v2/guide/syntax.html#Attributes)

```
  <button type="submit" class='btn btn-next btn-primary' name='next' value='Next' :disabled="isDisabled">Next</button>

  success: function(e) {
          if (e.status)
          {
           alert("Success")
            vm.pid=e.pid;
            console.log(vm.pid);
            vm.isDisabled = false; //enable button

        }
          else {
            vm.response = e;
            vm.isDisabled = true; //disable button

           alert("Registration Failed") 
          }
      }
```

**Update:**
Don't forget to add `isDisabled` in vue `data` object

```
data: {
   isDisabled: false
}
```

Comment: vue.js:435 [Vue warn]: Property or method "isDisabled" is not defined on the instance but referenced during render. Make sure to declare reactive data properties in the data option.

(found in <Root>)

Comment: You have to define `isDisabled` in vue `data: {}` object.

Answer (score 0):

do this

```
success: function(e) {
  if (e.status) {
    alert("Success")
    vm.pid = e.pid;
    console.log(vm.pid);
  } else {
    vm.response = e;
    alert("Registration Failed")
    e.preventDefault();//do this it can prevent your from to next tab

  }
}
```

Comment: submit:854 Uncaught TypeError: e.preventDefault is not a function
    at Object.success (submit:854)
    at c (jquery-1.10.2.min.js:4)
    at Object.fireWith [as resolveWith] (jquery-1.10.2.min.js:4)
    at k (jquery-1.10.2.min.js:6)
    at XMLHttpRequest.r (jquery-1.10.2.min.js:6)

Comment: at which elements you can call your success function @med

Comment: if status is 1 success fuction